# How to tests the constraints of a specific widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-constraint

I have a widget (`MyWidget`) in a screen (`MyScreen`) and I would like to write a test that verifies that specific constraints are applied to `MyWidgets`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tester.renderObject()` to obtain the `RenderObject` and get the constraints from it:

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(const MyScreen());

final renderObject = tester.renderObject(find.byType(MyWidget));
final constraintsMatcher = BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200); // For example, it can be any matcher.
expect(renderObject.constraints, constraintsMatcher);
```